# gcc not warning when passing constant number to size_t * argument

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags

My code is something like this:

```
#define ZERO_CONSTANT 0
foo(size_t * p_size);

foo(ZERO_CONSTANT); //Doesn't warn
```

Which gcc flag will make the call `foo(ZERO_CONSTANT)` to warn?

Comment: Unfortunately you're allowed to pass `0` for `NULL` so I don't think there is much you can do about this.

Comment: As Paul says [0 is a pointer literal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24212792/1708801).

Comment: My first question would be, why do you think this should be warned about? What is the error that you would be trying to catch? Do you want to be warned when your function is called with any kind of `0`?

Comment: @JensGustedt The point is semantics, not syntaxes. ZERO_CONSTANT has a meaning that has nothing to do with pointers or addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No compilation flag can possibly help you here. The C standard defines the literal 0 to stand in for the null pointer value of any type. Quite often you'll see `0`, `NULL` and `(void*)0`.

(Note well that this does **not** imply that the memory address is 0. Because it's *undefined behaviour* in general to assign an integral value to any pointer type, 0 is used as a placeholder literal for the null pointer).

Comment: The "could not possibly" bit is not true. Compilers are perfectly free to warn about anything, including 100% legal standard conforming things (and often do).

Comment: @n.m. True but I think I'll retain my assertion. I'm thinking of allowing that compilation flag in my "undefined behaviour nasal demon" compiler I'm working one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new option (available since [probably] GCC 4.7.x) - -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant. It does what you expect, but is valid only for C++... In C the code you presented is perfectly legal, as NULL is usually just "0".

Comment: Many implementations of the `stddef.h` header define `NULL` as `(void*)0`, the C standard (ISO 9899:2011) allows both `(void*)0` and `0`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, it's perfectly valid to pass `0` as a pointer. You can generate a warning with some compilers though if you are prepared to change the definition for `ZERO_CONSTANT`:

```
#define ZERO_CONSTANT ((int)0)
```

This then generates a warning with clang:

```
warning: expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'size_t *' (aka 'unsigned long *') [-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]
expanded from macro 'ZERO_CONSTANT'
#define ZERO_CONSTANT ((int)0)
```

Unfortunately it looks like gcc (4.8) still does not generate a warning in this case, even with `-Wextra`, although it's possible that there is a further `-W` switch that might enable this.

Comment: Couldn't enable -Wnon-literal-null-conversion flag in gcc nor find anything on google about it. Can you provide reference?

Comment: Sorry - that's a clang warning - I haven't checked gcc and just assumed that it would have something similar. I'll update the answer.