# Does the C standard have a website for defect reports?

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477209/is-void0-a-null-pointer-constant), the discussion seems to imply that there might be a defect in the C standard, further implied by the top answerer's last sentence:

> The authors of the standard merely neglected to say so.

I'm aware that C++ has an online website where you can search for defect reports, i.e. here is my search for [null pointer constant](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue?%40search_text=null+pointer+constant&id=&%40columns=id&title=&%40columns=title&creation=&activity=&%40columns=activity&%40sort=activity&section=&%40columns=section&status=&%40columns=status&submitter=&%40pagesize=50&%40startwith=0&%40action=search), but is there something similar for the C standard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keeping up with the C standards process is not as convenient as keeping up with the C++ process but by starting from the [WG14 page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) we can find the [Defect report summary for C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm) linked at the top and with a some extra work we can come up with the

- [WG14 Defect Report Summary for ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary-c99.htm).
- [What appear to be the pre C99 WG14 Defect Report Summary](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr.htm)

We can also find the lastest proposal by looking for the *mailings* also linked on the top of the site, currently:

- [Pre St. Louis 2014 Documents](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/PreStLouis2014.htm)

we can find a list of *mailings* going back to 1996 in the [documents](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/documents) section.

As far as I know `WG14` does not have a comparable site to [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/) which along with the [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/isocpp) makes it pretty easy to keep up with `WG21`.

For C++ I usually pick up the latest defect report list from [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/) when the latest pre-meeting mailing comes out, for example the latest one is the [Pre-Urbana mailing](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/10/pre-urbana). You can also find the most recent defect list by going to the [WG21 site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) and looking for *C++ Standard Core Language Issues List*:

- [C++ Standard Core Language Active Issues, Revision 91](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html)

For the draft standards documents the canonical question would be [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656). As far as I know all the public C and C++ draft standards are linked from that question.

Comment: The link Defect [report summary for C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm) ends in 2016. Have there been no more defect reports since then?

Answer (score 5):

The link in the question for C++ is to the WG21 (Working Group 21) site.  It may come as no surprise that there is one for C, namely WG14, here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/

The most recent defect report I see is this one: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm

There is a meeting in St. Louis just one week from now: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1861.htm

But while WG21 (for C++) has an active mailing list, I haven't found one for WG14.  This may seem strange, but it's possible that the way to get your voice heard is to physically appear in St. Louis or find a delegate who can.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a specific website, or dedicated mailing list.

The procedure for filing bug reports is outlined at URL:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/template.htm

Substitute the email address of the current Convenor, on the page:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/contacts
as necessary.

While not specified, an email subject line should include the phrase:
Draft C{nn} Defect: {title}

where {nn} is the version, 99, 11, 17, or 2x being commented on and a TC reference if needed, e.g. C99TC2, and {title} is a suggested value for the Subject: line of a Defect Report; to differentiate it from other types of email that box might get.

The URLs above are valid as of this writing as publicly accessible. Whether WG14 keeps them accessible is not in my control. Ymmv applies, in other words.