# How to track newer C++ std documents of given topic?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-design

Following is a C++ std document. The document number is N3721, which superseded the older N3634.

[image]

Obviously, it's easy to track older documents of given topic.

However, my question is:

**How to track newer documents of given topic?**

For example, if N3721 is superseded by a newer document, how to track the newer one?

Comment: I use an internet search engine, first.  If that fails, I ask on StackOverflow.  Usually someone has a link to the latest draft.

Comment: Related [How does the standards committee indicate the status of a paper under consideration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31033130/1708801) and on the X side [Does the C standard have a website for defect reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26477671/1708801)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the newer proposals (ones that start with the letter `P`) you can use [wg21.link redirect service](https://wg21.link/) to obtain the latest document:

> ```
> wg21.link - WG21 redirect service.
>
> Usage:    
>
> wg21.link/nXXXX
> wg21.link/pXXXXrX
>     Get paper.
>
> wg21.link/pXXXX
>     Get latest public revision of paper.
>
> wg21.link/std
> wg21.link/std{11,14,17}
>     Get working draft.
>
> wg21.link/cwgXXX
> wg21.link/ewgXXX
> wg21.link/lwgXXX
> wg21.link/lewgXXX
> wg21.link/fsXXX
> wg21.link/editXXX
>     Get issue.
>
> wg21.link/pXXXX/issue
>     Get issue for paper.
>
> wg21.link/*wgXXX/paper
>     Get paper for issue.
>
> wg21.link/index.json
> wg21.link/index.ndjson
> wg21.link/index.txt
> wg21.link/specref.json
>     Get everything.
>
> wg21.link/
>     Get usage.
>
> wg21.link/<something else>
>     Get 404.
>
> If you're Slackbot or Twitterbot:
>     Get OpenGraph metadata instead.
> ```

For example for `P0476: Bit-casting object representations` if we use [wg21.link/P0476](https://wg21.link/p0476) we obtain the latest version which is [P0476R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0476r2.html).

In my answer to [How does the standards committee indicate the status of a paper under consideration?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033334/1708801) I go into more details of the WG21 site and what documents you can find there.

#### Use the everything link for Pre P proposals

If we use the [wg21 redirect service Get Everything link](https://wg21.link/index.json) we can do a text search for the paper title. So for your example `Improvements to std::future<T> and Related APIs` we can see the last document is [N3857](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf):

> "N3857": {
>           "type": "paper",
>           "title": "Improvements to std::future and Related APIs",
>           "subgroup": "Concurrency",
>           "author": "N. Gustafsson, A. Laksberg, H. Sutter, S. Mithani",
>           "long_link": "http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf",
>           "link": "https://wg21.link/n3857",
>           "source": "http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/",
>           "date": "2014-01-16"
>       },