# Are NULL and 0 completely equivalent in C?

Tags: c, null, null-pointer

Are there "hard" reasons for using NULL in preference to 0 in C89/C99+, and interchanging them without a second thought as to deep concerns relating to standards compliance, even in code using very obscure aspects of C?

I am concerned with "hard" things like standards compliance, portability, undefined behaviour, unexpectedly different interactions with unanticipated corners of the language, whether the (hypothetical) Milliard Gargantubrain Segmented Memory Supercomputer would likely release its magic smoke, etc.

There is already a similar question on this site about C++, but I am not concerned about C++. I believe this is one of the areas where C++ behaviour may well differ from C.

In reality, issues of style and intent are important. But don't think that is useful to discuss in a Q&A forum, so they are not on-topic for this question.

The answers which I and others have found refer primarily to the use of NULL vs 0 in testing and assignment (a common case and one where it is safe to use them interchangeably). I'm asking if there is any thinking required *at all* to take arbitrarily weird but standards-compliant code which you have found, and syntactically substitute NULL for 0 (or possibly vice versa when the 0 is a pointer), ignoring whether that is a wise thing to do stylistically. It is hard to give examples of unanticipated interactions but, for example, function pointers often catch us out, maybe sizeof, ....

I've read the relevant standards sections which describe how 0 and NULL behave. Could someone help me with the impact of the way they are defined in the standard on interchanging them in obscure cases? Or else assure me that there are none.

Comment: I can't help thinking this /must/ be a duplicate, but can't find any record of such a question despite extensive clicking around.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/96780) (Tagged C++, C)

Comment: Related: [Is NULL always zero in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9894013/96780) (Tagged C)

Comment: Related: [Is ((void*)0) a null pointer constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26477209/96780) (Tagged C)

Comment: Related: [Why are NULL pointers defined differently in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7016861/96780) (Taggged C++, C)

Comment: see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0 the rules are the same in C++ and C(approximately), because C is a subset of C++(approximately)

Comment: "There is already a similar question on this site about C++" -> I suggest you link it

Comment: I'm lazy; I use `0`: `srand(time(0));`

Comment: I have no idea how to do that Antonio (is this markdown or what?), but I will try to find out.

Comment: Agreed @alk . Thanks for finding the duplicate. I did try really quite hard to find the duplicate, but my search-fu must be poor today! Should I delete this Q?

Comment: Deleting a question with answers isn't nice with respect to those answers, so just leave it as is. And btw: it was *Daniel Daranas* who found the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717771/null-or-0-in-c-hard-restrictions?noredirect=1#comment45722648_28717771

Comment: Indeed, to 20 answers in total, but you used your editorial and comprehension skills to find which of the links he posted contained the answer to my quesiton. That led me to examine that quesiton more closely and discover that the third answer was what I was after.

Comment: Having tried to apply this, actually I don't think it does answer my question! I'll clarify the question, though.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question, Daniel Datanas, @alp. Sorry, that was completely my fault: due to a dodgy sentence, in effect I asked a question other than the one I wanted an answer to. I've read so much about this today!

Comment: I just posted links to four related questions because they were all well formulated and could be useful to the readers of this one. I wasn't specifically aiming to find a duplicate of this one, which looked a too vague to me. Now the question is marked as duplicate, so further editing it isn't likely to help you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I didn't mean it as a criticism! Thanks for posting the links.

Comment: Especially after the edit, I think this isn't a duplicate question. I also edited the title and voted to reopen.

Comment: See also this on meta. From the discussion there, I'm starting to think that my edit was too substantial to make to a question. What a mess, :-( . Sorry.

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286877/my-answer-is-that-i-was-asking-the-wrong-question-question-editing-duplicat/286879#286879

Comment: @DanSheppard That is correct. You shouldn't just change one existing question to another just because you "really" wanted to ask something else. It doesn't matter if it was you who asked the original question. If you first asked A and then you realised you wanted to ask B, you should create a new question asking B.

Comment: At the time I considered it a clarification (that I was interested in all cases of the use of 0, not just in conditionals and direct assignment). I now think that wasn't so much a clarification as a different question. It's not so much changing "A" to "B" as "A" to "a" or maybe "ä".

To be honest, I wish I never wrote it at all. But what should I do now? Change it back again? Can someone with mod privileges maybe reverse my edit?

Comment: @DanSheppard I think you should be able to roll back your edit yourself ... in the edit history, does the previous revision have a "rollback" command next to it?

Comment: How do I see the edit history @Ajean ? If I click on edit I get a dropdown with revisions in, but I'm not sure that's what you mean, and there's no rollback mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  In each revision heading there should be clickable text such as "source" "link". Is "rollback" there? (It's not for me but I wouldn't be able to do it).  If it's not, it must be because the question's already closed.

Comment: No, I can't see anything like that @Ajean . I guess you're right, it's because it's closed. Oh well, we'll see wjat happens! I hope someone who's privileged comes to sort it out.

Answer (score 8):

Make the intentions of your code clear.

`NULL` for a pointer.

`0`, `0u`, `0l`, etc. for an integer.

`0.0` or `0.` or `.0` for a double.

`0.0f` or `0.f` or `.0f` for a float.

`'\0'` for a nul character.

In Objective-C, `nil` for a nil object.

Comment: `0.` for a floating point value will do. There is no need for any nimber of trailing zeros.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think in my question I mentioned that I was aware of the issues of intent and that this question does not concern those issues.

Answer (score 2):

Using the constant 0 (or any constant expression evaluating to 0) anyplace where `NULL` would be used is safe, as 0 is a **null pointer constant**.

This is defined in section 6.3.2.3p3 of the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) standards state:

> An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an
> expression  cast  to  type `void *`, is called a *null pointer
> constant*.<sup>55)</sup>  If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type,
> the resulting pointer,called a *null pointer* ,is guaranteed to
> compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

So `0`, when converted to a pointer type, is guaranteed to be converted to a null pointer regardless of how that particular system implements a null pointer.

Footnote 55 (66 in C11) from the above quote states:

> The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant.

Using my CentOS7 system as an example, it defines `NULL` as:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

While using 0 in place of `NULL` is safe, it is not *completely* equivalent, for example if it is used in a context doesn't necessarily expect a pointer.  As an example, `sizeof(0)` would evaluate to the size of an `int`, while `sizeof(NULL)` would (on my system at least) evaluate to the size of a `void *`.

The reverse, using NULL in place of 0, is not the same.  If you had this:

```
int x[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int *p = x + 0;
```

And replaced it with:

```
int x[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int *p = x + NULL;
```

The code would fail to compile since two pointers cannot be operands of the `+` operator.

Another example:

```
int x[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
void *p = (void *)x - 0;
printf("*p = %d\n", (int *)p);
```

While not strictly conforming to the standard, some implementations (like gcc) allow pointer arithmetic on `void *` types and would result in `3` being printed.  If you changed out 0 for `NULL`:

```
int x[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
void *p = (void *)x - NULL;
printf("*p = %d\n", (int *)p);
```

If you ran this code on a system that 1) allowed `void *` arithmetic and 2) used a non-zero address for a null pointer, you would be creating and dereferencing a pointer pointing before the start of the array and possibly not correctly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard specifically allows implementations to do

```
#define NULL 0
```

([http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3) : "The macros are NULL, which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant"; 0 is a null pointer constant.)

What this means in language-lawyer-ese is that search-and-replace changing every instance of the identifier NULL to the integer constant 0 cannot change the meaning of any *strictly conforming* program.

However, it is very difficult to be sure that a program is strictly conforming.  Other answers have given examples of cases where replacing NULL with 0 can, in fact, change the meaning of a program.  I would like to point out the converse: if a program has a bug due to `0` being interpreted as an integer constant rather than a null pointer constant, *replacing `0` with `NULL` does not fix the bug*.

A straightforward example of this is any use of [`execlp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp):

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", 0);  // UB: last argument is passed as (int)0
                              // rather than (char *)0 as expected by callee

execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);         // still buggy, NULL could expand to 0

execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);    // correct
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)NULL); // correct but asking for someone to
                                        // "simplify" the code by removing the cast
```

This type of problem becomes much more common when you're working on old code where not every function is declared with a prototype.