# How to correctly cast to compare a pointer to an explicit address range?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I do some malloc and afterwards I want to check wheather the result from malloc is in my RAM like this:

```
char (*message)[];
message = malloc(data_index);
if(message != NULL && message >= 0x20000000 && message < 0x20030000){
  //do something
}
```

It works, but I get a *warning: comparrison between pointer and integer*. I would like th get rid of this warning, but how?
The warning disappears, when I cast the integer to char, but this is a false solution, obviously.

```
if(message >= (char)0x20000000) {
```

I also tried to cast it to a double pointer, which I think is the right type, but the warning is still there.

```
if(message >= (char**)0x20000000) {
```

How do I get a woking if statement without a warning?

Comment: If you're on a system with virtual memory (basically every PC-like system the last couple of decades) the addresses you receive by `malloc` will not reflect actual physical locations of memory.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24212792/1025391

Comment: Furthermore, declaring `message` as a pointer to an array of unknown size doesn't make much sense in itself, and seldom makes sense generally (and does it even build?). And for your warning, a pointer to an array is not the same type as a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The memory address certainly can't be held in a `char` type and might not fit `int` type either.

Comment: _"I do some malloc and afterwards I want to check wheather the result from malloc is in my RAM"_: the return value of `malloc` is in your RAM, that's for sure and that's valid for any implementation.

Comment: Duplicate: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
char *message;
message = malloc(data_index);
if(message != NULL && message >= (char*)0x20000000 && message < (char*)0x20030000){
  // will do something
  // if message contains an address between 0x20000000 and 0x20030000
}
```

Be aware that this makes only sense on specific hardware (you didn't mention your target system).

On a modern desktop system (Mac/Windows/Linux) this makes no sense as all memory addresses are virtual.