# Why do I get a warning when using an int variable but not when using an integer constant?

Tags: c, null, integer, language-lawyer, constants

I have two versions of a piece of code. The first is by using an `int` variable as part of an expression for a condition test, the second by using an integer constant for the same - both represent the same integral value - `24`.

[1. code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmJdOpAA6pphJbU079IADY3Dy86CytbXQcnAA4ZOUwFbwYCZmICXz0DY1l5RToUtIJwm3tHZxlU9Mz/IOkq4stSqPKYgEoZVG1iZA4AcgBSQwBmS2QdLABqAeH1evxUADoEGewBgAYAQQ3NywJJ3WZLCDadgYB2ACEdydvJvcmANzTp4YARScNuGeutm7u8FQoGAwM9iG1Xm8Zh9rABVMxmU5bO7TK7/FG3VzEPZAoaGTh407DX6bFEXKF/c5vPodVggPoAVj6pAMfXWzNQ9PUk2kXR6mGmI04zII9PZbQ6AGsQMNhotZQrFUqgnS%2Btxmaz2aROX1mdIQOtSKK2TTSHBYDBEChULpXHh2GQKBA0Lb7eVkMAAJzGKj2giOfUQOxi5l2SxpACe9OFpBdulUBAA8rRWFGTaQsIdROwQxm8MREopHph9enMAAPRLaf25vZyXOsPB2YiRzRYaMi7G6DsdGj0JhsDg8fiCYSiEASMRSRt2fWQDqoVz5WilgC0AHU2KxJnqEkllBBTDUDC5TCVItFBO5PMvj1eQsvz2UnC5coXkg076%2B98vCukny0L6VEUX7Af%2BTQXuUnAdLy3S9FwtL0kyLK5jq5YxAEq4BNwkzAMgyCTJ6iyGJMEC4IQJCCsMLiTJoroOlR0G0SKIYSqQ0oMoaqrqqQ3acSh6Y6nqBpGqxZqWhASBdAQrjVuQlAunaDqCJg%2BBEEBfaMCwObDgA7i2rg9kISEaqh9JDNRky6YQCCTOhmHYbh%2BGEcRLEmmxCCYMwWBOCc7FcOsXH0jxfGGpqHL0sJhrGuKUoynKSqJQqKr0sMpmCZFonueJ8Dmlailuo6Ck2kp7rjCIXqBaQvqsP6xCBsG6ZhrQkYdrGNrxvQyaprmmYVTm6b4AWSTFqWWoVlWNbpnWqpajOLbEBGbb9DGBBdkZmkDjpvACMYY7iJIQhNnOfmLsupa7nk3gqGooFnhBz73je3igdeoS0ABl7fldBSfloWSCG%2B%2B60H%2BjQRI9r5/X4J5gWDzRfTBfLwdBxmMulWpoRhWE4eVoguesizrKR5HqYxpC0SVhVUYYELqG5sX%2BbK8pJYlqMhSA/HhdqmX6tFYl5ZJIDSbJBDyc6lPKcYqkURpdBaYOXC8PpzCGX0wqIWjAkY%2BZIwkdZBC2fZ2OTLjwD44T9M0h0nneeUfnccyoVaxFuoyCJMVW4zCUs0qqNpc73Oux7bGqoY6Mu5bbHFvV13cEAA%3D):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var = 24;

    if((!var) == NULL)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
}
```

[2. code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgAnKQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OrrLyinQMBMzEBH56BsaxmAo%2BickEYTb2ji4ySSlpAZnlBZZFkSXOAJQyqNrEyBwA5ACkhgDMlsg6WADUPf3q0gT4qAB0CBPYPQAMAIKra5YEo7rMlhBNmz0A7ABCm6NXo3hUUGBghtxN4/0AIhNvo9YAqmZmR3W13G50uwOubmI2zufUMnFhR36FyB11OH3WaK6LVYIC6AFYuqQDF0VoTULj1KNpG0OphxgNOISCLjSU0WgBrED9fpzbl8/kCgBsQlx3EJxNJpHJXUJ0hAK1IzJJWNIcFgMEQKFQujceHYZAoEDQOr1JWQwGcxioeoIjjlEDsLMJdksyQAnrjGaRjbpVAQAPK0Vge5WkLB7UTsJ1hvDEbKKABumDlocwAA9stpbdHtnJo6w8HZiO7NFhPUyobpyy0aPQmGwODx%2BIJhKIQBIxFIC3Y5ZAWqg3PFaCmALQAdTYrFGsrk8Z8KjUlQMnBMakKESigg8XiHS63wSH6%2BKThXWRyCRqe9Ps/PtDyKSPDRPZXyV5fD7qG5KnBa1PanS4bFcQJIlo2lNMAA5BRHQVuFGYBkGQUZnDmQxRggXBCBIel%2BhXUZNBNfUcJ/fCmSdNlSE5PEFRxLoxVIKtqNA0NpVleVFXI1UNQgJA2gINws3IShjV1fVBEwfAiGfWtGBYKMmwAd2LNxqxFfFxTA3E%2Blw0YFMIBBRkg6DYPgxDkNQsjlQohBMGYLAnEOSiuBWGjRUJRiFQlMlcTYhUlVZDkuR5AUQr5YVaP6DSWJ8jirK4%2BA1U1ETTQNYTtVEs1hhEC0XNIa1WFtYh7UdUMXVod1y29bVfXoQNg2jcNsqjUN8DjHIkxTSV00zbNQ1zWjJW7YtiDdUtui9AhK1UmT63k3gBGMVtxEkIRC17RyByHFMZziecIFMN9TEfTcV23EJfC0dJ9x3Hxju/GQbyHe9UkugJr12i98ju59plfV7l3fWpwmPQDWn/RsgPU5jJXAqCYLgrLRHMlY5hWdDMKk4jSHw9KUpwwwXnUSyAqc7leVCkK1Pojzoe8mUZHY/yVUSniQD4gSCCEo1cbE4wJKw6S6FkhsuF4JTmBUrpGUhkCvKlLSBjQvSCAMoz4dGRHgGR1HiaxFobLskpHNo6mQCYuXWIZvzyMCsmKcpiKophmKmYo2jDCdundYopMivnbggA%3D):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if((!24) == NULL)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
}
```

---

When I attempt to compile the first version, I get the warning:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer

from gcc, and

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *') [-Wpointer-integer-compare]

from clang.

When I compile the almost equivalent code by using the same value just as integer constant, everything is fine. Why?

---

My research so far:

I looked into C18 and found on section 6.4.4 "Constants":

First under Subsection /2 and /3:

> "*2 - Each constant shall have a type and the value of a constant shall be in the range of representable values for its type.*"
>
> "*3 - Each constant has a type, determined by its form and value, as detailed later.*".

And second under Subsection /5:

> "*The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.*"

The following list:

[image: list]

Thus, an integer constant with no suffix and relative to the representable value of `24` should have type `int`.

---

I understand the warning itself and know that `NULL` usually on most implementations expands to `(void*) 0`. Thus, it is reasonable that this warning is thrown.

But why does the warning not occur when using the same value as integer constant?

Comment: Use NULL for pointers — do not use NULL when not working with pointers.  It is a null pointer constant.  See C11 [§7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19):  _The macros are

        `NULL`
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and…_

Comment: Your literal `(!24)` is seen by the compiler as `(0)` - which is a valid pointer constant (in fact, the *only* valid pointer constant). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212940/10871073).

Comment: `!24` is zero, and zero can be compared to `NULL` (it can be converted to `void *` without further ado).

Comment: Note that `if((!0) == NULL)` should also raise a warning.

Comment: Confirmed, Clang and GCC warn with `(!0) == NULL` but not `(!1) == NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C11 6.3.2.3/3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   void *, is called a null pointer constant.

And from 6.5.9/2 regarding equality operators `==` and `!=`:

> One of the following shall hold:
>   ...
>   — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Note that integer constant expressions are not limited to integer constants (0, 42, etc.) but can also include operators acting on them like `5+5-10`.

`!24` is an integer constant expression with the value 0, and therefore counts as a null pointer constant. The `==` operator is allowed to act between a pointer and a null pointer constant, which makes `(!24) == NULL` a valid comparison.

In your first example, `!var` is not an integer constant expression because it includes a variable operand, and thus cannot be compared with a pointer.

Caveat: In most implementations, `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` and the above is correct. However, the standard allows it to be defined it as any null pointer constant such as `0`. If this is the case, then the comparison `(!var) == NULL` will compile because it is the same as `(!var) == 0`.

Comment: Had the value in question been 0 instead of 24, the compiler would have generated a warning.